# How to interprete ACF and PACF functions from statsmodels?

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying to determine `p` and `q` values for an ARMA model. The time series is already stationary and I was looking to `ACF` and `PACF` plots, but I need to get those `p` and `q` values "on the go" (like performing a simulation).

I noticed that in `statsmodels` there are actually two functions for `acf` and `pacf`, but I'm not understanding how to use them properly.

This is how the code looks like

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf

>>>acf(data,qstat=True)
(array([1.        , 0.98707179, 0.9809318 , 0.9774078 , 0.97436479,
        0.97102392, 0.96852746, 0.96620799, 0.9642253 , 0.96288455,
        0.96128443, 0.96026672, 0.95912503, 0.95806287, 0.95739194,
        0.95622575, 0.9545498 , 0.95381055, 0.95318588, 0.95203675,
        0.95096276, 0.94996035, 0.94892427, 0.94740811, 0.94582933,
        0.94420572, 0.9420396 , 0.9408416 , 0.93969163, 0.93789606,
        0.93608273, 0.93413445, 0.93343312, 0.93233588, 0.93093149,
        0.93033546, 0.92983324, 0.92910616, 0.92830326, 0.92799811,
        0.92642784]),
 array([  2916.11296684,   5797.02377904,   8658.22999328,  11502.6002944 ,
         14328.44503612,  17140.72034976,  19940.48013538,  22729.69637912,
         25512.09429552,  28286.18290207,  31055.33003897,  33818.82409725,
         36577.1270353 ,  39332.49361223,  42082.0755955 ,  44822.94911057,
         47560.49941212,  50295.38504714,  53024.59880222,  55748.57526173,
         58467.72758802,  61181.8659989 ,  63888.25003765,  66586.53110019,
         69276.46332225,  71954.97102175,  74627.57217707,  77294.54406888,
         79952.23080669,  82600.54514273,  85238.73829645,  87873.86209917,
         90503.68343426,  93126.47509834,  95746.79574474,  98365.17422285,
        100980.34471949, 103591.88164688, 106202.58634768, 108805.3453693 ]),
 array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]))


>>>pacf(data)
array([ 1.        ,  0.98740203,  0.26463067,  0.18709112,  0.11351714,
        0.0540612 ,  0.06996315,  0.05159168,  0.05358487,  0.06867607,
        0.03915513,  0.06099868,  0.04020074,  0.0390229 ,  0.05198753,
        0.01873783, -0.00169158,  0.04387457,  0.03770717,  0.01360295,
        0.01740693,  0.01566421,  0.01409722, -0.00988412, -0.00860644,
       -0.00905181, -0.0344616 ,  0.0199406 ,  0.01123293, -0.02002155,
       -0.01415968, -0.0266674 ,  0.03583483,  0.0065682 , -0.00483241,
        0.0342638 ,  0.02353691,  0.01704061,  0.01292073,  0.03163407,
       -0.02838961])
```

How can I get `p` and `q` with this functions? The `acf` function returns only 1 array if qstat is set to `False`

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the order of an ARMA(p,q) model using estimated ACFs/PACFs is usually not the best approach. This is simply because in case of an ARMA process both the ACF and PACF slowly decay (in absolute terms) for increasing lags. So you cannot really infer the lag order from it. Instead they are mostly used for pure AR/MA models in which you observe a clear cutoff in either of the two series (but even then it is more of a graphical approach).

If you want to determine p and q "on the fly" for an ARMA model it seems more reasonable to use information criteria (e.g. AIC, BIC, etc.). `statsmodels` provides the function [`arma_order_select_ic()`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.arma_order_select_ic.html) for this very purpose. So what you want is something like this:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import arma_order_select_ic
arma_order_select_ic(data, max_ar=4, max_ma=4, ic='bic')
```